# Unable to Retrieve Text from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-2013

Using JS in CSOM for SharePoint 2013, I'm having difficulty retrieving the text from an element. This is from a custom display form for a custom list. The column type in question is a multi-line text box, but is rendered differently in the display form due to the form override script being used.

Inspect element in Chrome reveals:

```
<span class="formOverride" id="itemData" data-displayName="RequisitionItems">
     <div dir>1||X-HEDC.000.000||GC-M||Critical Item #42||1||10||$10.00||</div>
</span>
```

Every attempt at retrieving the text in the div element has resulted in an empty string.

```
document.getElementById("itemData").innerText;

$("#itemData").text();

$("span#itemData.formOverride").text();

$("span#itemData.formOverride").children().text();
```

When I display the DOM properties for the span, the innerText is even listed properly, but still an empty string is returned.

What am I missing...?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: More info...
Override script:

```
$("span.formOverride").each(function()
{
        //get the display name from the custom layout
        displayName = $(this).attr("data-displayName");
        elem = $(this);
        //find the corresponding field from the default form and move it
        //into the custom layout
        $("table.ms-formtable td").each(function(){
            if (this.innerHTML.indexOf('FieldName="'+displayName+'"') != -1){
                $(this).contents().appendTo(elem);
            }
        });
});
```

So, the span posted originally has the contents from the default display form appended. I've never had any troubles accessing the formOverride information previously, so this is just being odd.

Further update:

Seems I cannot access any element's text on the page. It also appears that this is an issue particular to a SharePoint display form. I copied in full the script/html from my Edit page and pasted it into the Display page's corresponding file. In Edit the text returns fine, but in Display the text returned is an empty string.

Comment: Where are you running this script?

Comment: It's in an aspx document linked to a CEWP in a function on page load.

Comment: I am guessing this is a delegated element? Works fine **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/C3RmL/)**

Comment: Did you wrap it in DOM ready? `$(function(){$("#itemData").text();});` ?

Comment: All page load scripts originate from within the `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: more correct should be $("#itemData div").text();

Comment: `$('<span class=formOverride" id="itemData" data-... Item #42||1||10||$10.00||</div></span>').text()` works so...

Comment: Check this, [working](http://jsfiddle.net/C3RmL/1/), within `$(document).ready(function(){...});`.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
$("#itemData").children().first().text();
```

Or

```
$("#itemData").find("div").text();
```

Or

```
$("#itemData div").text();
```

Comment: Returns the same empty string as the previous attempts to access this.

Comment: Hmm... Keep in mind `<span><div></div></span>` is not valid HTML. Is `#itemData` unique in your DOM?

Comment: The span/div nesting is being produced automatically by SharePoint. Well... the span is mine, and the div element may be how SP handles textarea elements. The id is unique.

Comment: All empty strings. I get the impression now that it isn't my selector that's the problem, but rather an issue inherent with SP's Display form. Post updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup has a quote opening error

```
<span class="formOverride" id="itemData" data-displayName="RequisitionItems">
     <div dir>1||X-HEDC.000.000||GC-M||Critical Item #42||1||10||$10.00||</div>
</span>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    console.log($("#itemData").text())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PXZCr/)

Comment: The missing quote was a typo on my part when creating the post here. In the page the mark-up has it. Thanks.